# Relationship field entries total count

Tags: relationships

Is there a way to get the total number of items chosen in a multiple relationships field?

Comment: Grrr EE Docs are missing, and inconsistent!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try this tag:

`{relationship_field:total_results}`

Example:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="xyz"}
        {relationship_field}
           {relationship_field:total_results}
        {/relationship_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Yup. That is what I need.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Bhashkar Yadav's answer, this worked successfully for me:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='channel_xyz' status='not closed'}
    {if relationship_field:total_results > 0}
        ...do something!
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

...that is, having it outside of the relationship field loop.