# Can't get total results for relationship field

Tags: templates, relationships

I am trying to use count and total_results to detect the last item but total_results is not working in a relationship field. I can get the count and verify there are multiple entries but not the total.

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="the-title"}

{project_images}


    {!-- working --}
    {project_images:count}    

    {!-- not working --}
    {project_images:total_results}

{/project_images}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

produces:

1   2   3   4   5   6   7

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that is wierd, according to [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13585/relationship-field-entries-total-count) (which I'm sure you've seen) that should be working...

What do you get? Blank or the wrong number??

Also can you confirm the version of EE you are using please?