# Total items from relationship field

Tags: templates, relationships, ee3

I'm trying to wrap items in a ul if there are more than one, however I am getting the if always false, this is caused due to `{feature_content:total_results}` returning false. 
I end up with `<h1>TOTAL: ""</h1>` so it's not even zero.

Can someone enlighten me as to what I'm missing?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="feature"} 
<!-- Feature Section -->
<div class="layoutholder">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 large-10">
            <h1>TOTAL: "{feature_content:total_results}"</h1>
            {if feature_content:total_results > 1}
                <ul class="bxslider-features">
                    {feature_content}
                        <li><div>{feature_content:content}</div></li>
                    {/feature_content}
                </ul>
            {if:else}
                {feature_content}
                    <div>{feature_content:content}</div>
                {/feature_content}
            {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Based on this answer [Relationship field entries total count](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13585/relationship-field-entries-total-count#answer-34606) I would have thought the above to work.

Answer (score 0):

This fails for me:

```
{if feature_content:total_results > 1}
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
{if feature_content:total_results >= 1}
```

If it's less than 1, there are no relationships to show anyway.

Comment: Well, I should potentially have an initial if clause for if not to not show anything. But currently that doesn't matter as the initial problem remains of `feature_content:total_results` returning null (there are items as `feature_content:content` is spitting out what I would expect).

Comment: From what I've gathered it's something to do with counts getting messed up when a relationship field is looped inside `{exp:channel:entries}`

Comment: When I try this locally and make the change to >=, it counts correctly. You're not wrapping it with a {feature_content} pair as well?

Comment: Nope, that's the literal template in my question, not even summarized. Just double checking EE3 right?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
{feature_content:total_rows}
```

Would be super useful if this was actually documented anywhere I could find!